# How to validate @Xml.propOrder annotation values?

Tags: java, xml, annotations

My team has been running into a recurring problem while serializing objects to XML:  the class properties get updated, but the `@Xml.propOrder` annotation values do not (people forget), which causes the following error:

> Property baz appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists.

How can I automate a unit test to check all classes that declare `@Xml.propOrder` for undeclared fields or typos in the annotation value?

E.g:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name = "FooBar", propOrder = { "bar", "baz", "foo" })
public class FooBar {

    private String foo;
    private int bar;

    // getters and setters here...
}
```

IntelliJ sometimes can pick up the error during linting, but some team members use Eclipse, so code gets comitted, maven does not spew any warnings, and wrong code goes to test/QA. Also, our team cannot also change the build script, it's controlled and standardized company-wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cobbled together a test that uses Guava to load information about all classes under a package name, load them, check if they have the @XmlType annotation, and if so, compares the values of the propOrder element with the class properties obtained through reflection.

I'm not totally happy with it, I wanted to use the same mechanism that Java uses to validate the annotations. But hey, it works.

```
package com.mycompany.datamodel;

import com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath;
import com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath.ClassInfo;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PropOrderTest {

    @Parameter
    public Class clazz;

    @Parameters(name = "Test @XmlType.propOrder: {0}")
    public static Collection<Class> data() throws IOException {
        ClassPath classPath = ClassPath.from(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        String packageName = PropOrderTest.class.getPackage().getName();
        Set<ClassInfo> allClasses = classPath.getTopLevelClassesRecursive(packageName);
        List<Class> annotatedClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();
        for (ClassInfo info : allClasses) {
            Class clazz = info.load();
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(XmlType.class)) {
                annotatedClasses.add(clazz);
            }
        }
        return annotatedClasses;
    }

    @Test
    public void testPropOder() throws IOException {
        XmlType xmlType = (XmlType) clazz.getAnnotation(XmlType.class);
        Set<String> propOrder = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(xmlType.propOrder()));
        // remove empty string returned when propOrder is not declared
        propOrder.remove("");
        List<String> fieldNames = getFieldNames();
        propOrder.removeAll(fieldNames);

        assertTrue(formatMessage(propOrder), propOrder.isEmpty());

    }

    private List<String> getFieldNames() {
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(fields.length);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            names.add(field.getName());
        }
        return names;
    }

    private String formatMessage(Collection<String> propOrder) {
        String message = null;
        String props = "'" + StringUtils.join(propOrder.toArray(), "', '") + "'";
        if (propOrder.size() > 1) {
            message = "Properties %s appear in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such properties exist in class %s (%s.java:1).";
        } else {
            message = "Property %s appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists in class %s (%s.java:1).";
        }
        return String.format(message, props, clazz.getName(), clazz.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```